# How to transition from Obsolete ContactOptions to ExecutionOptions in xConnect xdbContext.GetAsync method

Tags: xconnect

I am in the process of creating a Contact in `xConnect` and encountering the following warning message.
[image]

What are the modifications needed to convert code from utilizing the `ContactExpansionOptions` parameter to the `ExecutionOptions` parameter?

[image]

Comment: For SEO reasons, replace your screenshots with code snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the constructore of `ContactExecutionOptions` which accepts `ContactExpandOptions` as a parameter like that:

```
new ContactExecutionOptions(new ContactExpandOptions(new string [] { PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey));
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance; it was effective.

Comment: @SunilRana Please mark as an accepted answer if the above solved your issue.

Comment: @SunilRana And please use the code in your question along with the image for SEO.